# Volume ID using mkisofs and cdrecord

Tags: burning, dvd-burning, cd-burning

I'm trying to specify the volume id of a cd/dvd when using mkisofs and cdrecord afterwards.
I figured out that there's an option `-V volumeid` of mkisofs. The manpage says that 32 characters can be given here. Unfortunately, it seems that those 32 characters are padded, even though my given volume id has less than 32 characters (padded with spaces). IMHO this is really ugly.

Is there any way to prevent mkisofs or cdrecord, respectively, from padding the volume id?

My call to mkisofs is `mkisofs -V "MyDVD" -J -R -o foo.iso`

My call to cdrecord is `cdrecord -dao dev=/dev/dvd foo.iso`

Any suggestions welcome and appreciated.

Kind regards.